# Remotely call python script through keyword "Execute Command" of SSHLibrary cannot returned

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm working on automation testing based on robot framework and adopt SSHLibrary to execute command on remote server. But when i tried to execute a python script which has sys.exit(0) in the end, keyword "Execute Command" cannot return.

My sample code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
     Open Connection    192.168.1.1
     Login    root    abcd
     Execute Command    test.py --param1 --param2
```

I also tried to add another option "timeout=60" to "Open Connection", but the result is the same.

- Robot framework version: 3.0
- SSHLibrary version: 2.1.2

Any suggetions?

Comment: What makes you think that `Execute Command` cannot return? What is it doing? Does your test hang?

Comment: I double checked the backend script at the same time, using ps -ef to check its PID and tailf its debug log. the script can finally exit properly that no process running, no debug logs output.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add 'Python' after you call Execute Command.

So like this:

```
Execute Command   Python  test.py --param1 --param2
```